# How can I reverse a delayed animation?

Tags: css, css-transitions

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gom9bhr/)

I have a square, on hover it moves down 10px then rotates. When coming off the hover I wish for it to rotate back, then move back to 0px.

Unfortunately it doesn't do the animations in reverse order.

So it should, on hover:

1. Move 10px down.
2. Rotate 45 degrees.

And off hover:

1. Rotate back to 0 degrees.
2. Move back to original position of 0px;

Code:

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top 0.3s ease;
  transition: transform 0.3s 0.3s ease;
}

div:hover{
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: To be clear:  Both parts of the animation are playing in reverse, but in the wrong order (on the way back it rotates then moves upward)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got 2 small problems with your code, the first is that you set `transition` twice.  In this case the second will simply overwrite the first.  Simple fix: comma separated list:

```
transform top 0.3s ease, 0.3s 0.3s ease;
```

Now, as for reversing the order in which the animations play - what we'll want to do is set a different order for the transitions based on which direction we're moving.  If we're in our hover state, we always want to be moving forward, otherwise in reverse:

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, top 0.3s 0.3s ease;
}

div:hover{
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/7gom9bhr/3/)

**CSS**

```
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, top 0.3s 0.3s ease;
}

div:hover{
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: top 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s 0.3s ease;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/7gom9bhr/3/

Comment: Setting `transition` twice will simply overwrite the first value